# How to exit the output from list mode in python?

Tags: python

The goal is to display the output of the list as an integer. e.g. :

```
>>> x = 3498
>>> x_list = [int(digit) for digit in str(x)]
>>> x_list.reverse()
>>> print(x_list)
[8, 9, 4, 3]
```

The output is a list.

And what is my expected output :

```
8943
```

Comment: This question is a little confusing because you say the goal is "display the output of the list as an integer". But you show all this other stuff starting with an integer. Is the question about converting a list to an integer or reversing an integer?

Answer (score 3):

you can also just reverse the list if that's your goal :).

```py
x = 3498
x = str(x)
print(int(x[::-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a digit of the form `abcd` is actually `(a * 10**3) + (b * 10**2) + (c * 10**1) + (d * 10**0)`. By using this fact, you can do your reversion without even using `x_list.reverse()`:

```py
x = 3498
x_list = [int(digit) for digit in str(x)]
reversed_x = sum(digit * 10**i for i, digit in enumerate(x_list))
assert reversed_x == 8943
```

Or, to make everything in a single operation (thanks to @Chiheb Nexus for the suggestion):

```py
x = 3498
reversed_x = sum(int(digit) * 10**i for i, digit in enumerate(str(x)))

assert reversed_x == 8943
```

Comment: You can simply do: `reversed_x = sum(int(digit) * 10**i for i, digit in enumerate(str(x))) `

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 3498
x_list = [digit for digit in str(x)]
x_list.reverse()
x_list = int(''.join(x_list))
print(x_list)
8943
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to convert to string:

```
import math

def reverse_digits(num):
    q, r = divmod(num, 10)
    if q == 0:
        return r
    return r * 10**(int(math.log10(q)) + 1) + reverse_digits(q)

print(reverse_digits(3498))  # 8943
```